# Choose backgrounds in a select box on the website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am not very good with javascript and php, and I understood to make this work I will need to use js and php.

I want to create a "select box" with 4 different images.
There will be a default image, but in this select box the users should be able to select one of the other 3 backgrounds if they want to.

I am not sure why it will not work, so I'll show you my files below:

Here is the webclient.html:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop1" />
        <label for="drop1" class="dropdown_button">Background <span class="arrow"></span></label>
        <ul class="dropdown_content">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1);">Navy Aero</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage(2);"><img src="img/b_webclient_2.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage(3);">Gray Bullet</li>                                
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage(4);">Dark Pheonix</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- note that the <img src> was just to test if it would work if I placed image in. -->
    </div>
```

I have also included the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/changebg.js"></script>
```

changebg.js:

```
function changeImage(number)
{
    $.post('core/changebg.php',{number:number},
        function(data)
        {
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url("img/'+number+'.png")');
        });
}
```

changebg.php:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['number'])) 
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['image'] = $_POST['number'];
    }

?>
```

The final product is like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xhuA.jpg

When I click any of them nothing happends.

Comment: Added some changes to my answer below including a layout effect that fades out the page to black for the change so it's not so sudden, and abrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use purely jQuery for this with something like the following, just replacing `backgroundColor` for `backgroundImage` and the values of the selects to the paths of the images, or the number of the image and use the bg variable in the path for the id like `'img/'+bg+'.png'`

```
$('#bgs').on('change', function() {
    var bg = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
        body = $('body');
    body.css('backgroundColor', bg);
});
```

### [JSFiddle Color Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/VEM5b/)

### [JSFiddle Image Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/xkSDA/)

### [JSFiddle Effect Transition Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/gEYQz/)

Comment: In value what would I put in? Like "dark tether" or like "webclient_1.png" ?

Comment: You'd use `value="img/webclient_1.png"`

Comment: I don't mean to make alot of trouble, but could I use my code, because it is easier to style the whole dropdown box with divs instead of selects.